# SelectedItem Binding in Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, selecteditem

I have a Datagrid, that shows Columns, that are added by setting the ItemsSource-Property via Code. I also have two columns, that are added by XAML (a Button and a combination of Image and Button in a Grid).
Now I am editing some cells and want to read them.
In Windows Forms it was possible to read specific cells but this is not possible or recommended in WPF, I read. So I want to use a SelectedItem-Binding. My Problem is, that the SelectedItem is always null. Maybe there is a problem with the Datagrid because of the "mixed adding" of columns or I am doing something wrong.

Here is the part of my Code:

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="12,162,12,12" Name="dgExisting" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="24" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#50000000" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#50000000" SelectionMode="Single" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCell_Centering}" CellEditEnding="dgExisting_CellEditEnding" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">            
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Password" Width="60" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource Flat}" Click="btnDgChangePassword_Click">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding imgStatus}" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding PasswordState}" Margin="16,-5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="50" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="btnDgRemove_Click" Style="{StaticResource Flat}">
                            <Image Source="Images/redcross16.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And the Code how I add the columns by code:

```
//Create Table for Gridview
DataTable dtList = new DataTable();
dtList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Username"));
dtList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PasswordState"));
dtList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Domain"));
dtList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description"));
dtList.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id"));

foreach (UserCredential uc in credentialList)
{
    DataRow dR = dtList.NewRow();                
    dR["Username"] = uc.getUsername();
    dR["PasswordState"] = (uc.getPassword().Length > 0 ? "yes":"no");
    dR["Domain"] = uc.getDomain();
    dR["Description"] = uc.getDescription();
    dR["id"] = uc.getId();

    dtList.Rows.Add(dR);
}

dtList.Columns.Add("imgStatus");

for (int i = 0; i < dtList.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dtList.Rows[i]["imgStatus"] = (dtList.Rows[i]["PasswordState"].ToString() == "yes" ? "Images/key16.png" : "");
}

dgExisting.ItemsSource = dtList.DefaultView;
dgExisting.Columns[getColumnId("Password")].DisplayIndex = 2; //reorder Key-Image
dgExisting.Columns[getColumnId("PasswordState")].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; 
dgExisting.Columns[getColumnId("imgStatus")].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden; 
dgExisting.Columns[getColumnId("id")].Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: Where is the SelectedItem property?  What is it's datatype?  Is the DataContext of the grid set anywhere?

Comment: Have you tried adding an `SelectionChanged` event handler in the code-behind to see if the problem is that the selection is not changing in the DataGrid or if the problem is with the binding?

Comment: @KDiTraglia The `SelectedItem` is at the end of the first line of XAML, you have to scroll over quite a bit, but it is there.  If he can see his rows (and thus make a selection) it's reasonable to assume the `DataContext` is properly set.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I see it in the xaml, I was inquiring about the backing property it is bound to.  And the rows show up because he is setting the ItemsSource of the grid explicitly in the code, so the DataContext may have not been set.

Comment: @KDiTraglia Yep, good point I was scrolling around to see the biding on the `SelectedItem` and didn't even catch that.  Good catch! =)

Comment: @KDiTraglia The DataType of the Property is DataRowView and I also tried my UserCredential-Class. Both are not working and never touched when I set some Breakpoints. A DataContext if the Grid isn't set.
at CodingGorilla: I set a Beep everytime the selection changed and it beeps. So there is a change of the selection.

Comment: I did a quick test of setting a `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to a `DataTable.DefaultView`, and binding the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to a `DataRowView` property in code-behind, and it works fine. Your problem must be in the code you aren't showing. I'd highly recommend using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to look through your code while it's running and make sure your `DataContext` and `SelectedItem` binding are correct

Comment: @Rachel The Snoop program looks nice but doesn't work for me. It doesn't show anything, when I click on the button to snoop something
The Reason why I see nothing in the DataRowView may be because of the Column with the button and the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your C# code you are not creating a binding to the DataGrid's item source.

```
dgExisting.ItemsSource = dtList.DefaultView;
```

is **NOT** a binding. This is why your SelectedItem always null in your XAML binding. To create a binding in code you would need to do something like:

```
var binding = new Binding("ItemsSource");
binding.Source = dtList.DefaultView;
dgExisting.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Setting bindings WPF in C# is a bit of a smell. There may be a reason that you have to do it. But, I would suggest redesigning your application to better follow the MVVM pattern so that you can just set your binding in XAML.